# Page URL not working due to physical directory

Tags: permalinks, directory

I have a page named http://www.mysite.com/whitepapers/ and it worked fine. I have now added a physical "whitepapers" directory and has since broken my permalink for the page. I realize that it has something to do with content negotiation after reading [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/my-permalinks-are-broken-can-i-use-mod-rewrite-to-ignore-a-physical-file) but the fix did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP Page and Subdirectory with same name](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still looking for an answer, have a look at 
[WP Page and Subdirectory with same name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name)

Basicalli I will have to rename the folder on my server.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really content negotiation at all, since there is an actual matching directory. Your server will not reach WordPress to process the URI if it encounters a directory first. You will need to either rename your directory or change the permalink for the page in order to have both working.

Comment: thanks for your reply but neither is an option. There seem to be couple of workarounds in which you set rewrite conditions on those physical folders which are then handled by wordpress but I would like to see if that can be avoided.

Comment: How are you expecting the two to work together?

Comment: I'm just checking to see what is possible.

Comment: Anything is possible... except two different things being accessed at the same location. Which one do you expect to be served up? Judging by another one of your questions (which you should have linked to if it's related), you want the WordPress page and "pretty" uploads, so you are definitely going to have to name your directory something else and use .htaccess to serve it up under /whitepapers/. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name